# What Is The 3-stud Wide Red Cabinet Frame Piece In Picture?

Tags: piece-information, part-identification

I would like to know the name and part number for the red frame piece in picture. The one that is holding the white cupboard door.

[image]

Answer (score 6):

[image]

Hey Nancy!

[*Part# 4532 Container, Cupboard 2 x 3 x 2*](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=4532#T=S&O=%7B%22iconly%22:0%7D)